# How can I explain that data won't cross threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Not sure if this is really the best place to ask.
Let's say my code looks something like this

```
void StartThreads()
{
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(DoWork);
    thread1.Start(data1);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(DoWork);
    thread2.Start(data2);
}

void DoWork(object o)
{
    WorkerClass c = new WorkerClass();
    c.DoWork(o);
}
```

How best can I explain that random data from the `thread1` instance of `c` isn't going to get into the data of the `thread2` instance of `c`?
`data1` and `data2` are separate instances of `NamedPipeServerStream`.
Note that the `DoWork()` function itself has for quite a while been multi-threaded and has never jumbled data between the classes involved there, but I guess adding another layer here is scary for the higher-ups, since data getting jumbled around could mean very large fines.

Comment: build a test such that non-random data is provided as input, and therefore you can inspect the output for jumbling

Comment: But a test won't necessarily catch the problem if there is some one-in-a-million issue with .NET threading.

Comment: If there's a one-in-a-million issue with .Net threading, a million users running tests would have found it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good luck with the higher ups, but here is the technical reason why this is OK.

Regardless of threading, when you call a function, it gets a brand new **stack frame**. That is, all of its local variables and arguments get a specific piece of memory that is specific *to that function call*. Any other calls to this function will not touch that memory.

Just calling the function on a new thread does not change this behavior, so your arguments are "safe" when called in the provided code (assuming they are just data and don't depend on a shared resource or each other of course). This is true because a new thread is still a function invocation (albeit on a different thread).

If those two streams are *in any way* related, then you have a race condition and a problem waiting to happen, so make sure they are truly not shared/dependent.

In other words, assuming no shared resources, the code is the same as writing (thanks to @ChrisHaas):

```
DoWork(data1);
DoWork(data2);
```

Which no sane programmer would object to as far as data modification goes.

Comment: To say what you said in a slightly different way, the OP's code can basically thought of as `DoWork(data1); DoWork(data2);`. As long as `DoWork` doesn't modify\affect shared\global state most programmers (higher ups) wouldn't have a problem running these two and wouldn't care about the order of them, either.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, excellent rewording! I have included the essentials of it in my answer, feel free to edit if you feel it could be better!